# postfix/opendkim not sign email from php on second domain

Tags: php, postfix, php-fpm, opendkim

I have two domains, called them `example1.com` and `example2.com`

on `example1.com` all emails sent with dkim sign.
on `example2.com` emails from php sent **without** dkim sign, but if send email from console, email will be signed.

*ex. console command:*

```
php -r 'mail("myemail@yandex.ru", "TEST", "TEST TEXT", "MIME-Version:
1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\nFrom: no-reply <admin@example2.com>\r\n");'
```

#### Server

Centos 7
php-fpm + nginx

#### opendkim.conf

```
# grep "^[^#;]" /etc/opendkim.conf
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
LogWhy                  Yes
Syslog                  Yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
Mode                    sv
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
UMask                   022
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
```

#### main.cf

```
# grep "^[^#;]" /etc/postfix/main.cf 
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = example1.com
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
relay_domains = example1.com,example2.com
relayhost =
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases


debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol         = 2
```

#### TrustedHosts

```
# grep "^[^#;]" /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
localhost
127.0.0.1
::1
example1.com
example2.com
```

#### KeyTable

```
grep "^[^#;]" /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
default._domainkey.example1.com example1.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/example1.com/default
default._domainkey.example2.com example2.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/example2.com/default
```

#### SigningTable

```
# grep "^[^#;]" /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
*@example1.com default._domainkey.example1.com
*@example2.com default._domainkey.example2.com
```

#### transport

```
# grep "^[^#;]" /etc/postfix/transport 
example1.com smtp:mx.yandex.ru
example2.com smtp:mx.yandex.ru
```

### php.ini

```
# grep sendmail_path /etc/php.ini
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix -t -i
```

#### test.php

```
<?php
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply <admin@example2.com>\r\n";
if (mail('myemail@yandex.ru', 'TEST', 'TEST', $headers)){
    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    echo 'FAIL';
}
```

This config need just for send emails, for receive emails I use pdd.yandex.ru
Where is problem with `example2.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify a "From:" header in the sendmail command. Opendkim only signs Mails with an aligned "From:" header.

Comment: I added `test.php`, there header `From` is exists., but on `example2.com` sending without dkim sign, if it was sent from php, but from console it sending with dkim sign.